# system.nullreferenceexception while redirecting to page

Tags: asp.net

I am checking session in each content page and even in master page also.It is working fine with all pages other than one page(Test.aspx).In Test.aspx page it gives error when session is null.How can I handle this?

```
If(Session["LoginId"] == null)
{
  Response.redirect("SessionClear.aspx",false)
}
```

In SessionClear.aspx page ,I am clearing session and redirecting to Login page.

Comment: you may not have session enabled for that page (check aspx page's page directive, `EnableSessionState=`).  For your check, it would be `if(Session == null || Session["LoginId"] == null)`

Comment: Hi,I have checked.I have not mention about EnableSessionState (either true/false/read only)

Comment: have you tried **HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginId"] == null**